# how to set up reading a remote private github respository

Tags: github, authorization, jgit

I'm trying to walk a remote private git repository and list all the folders, subfolders, and files. The code I use is below, as well as the authorization exception.

Code:

```
package com.example.proofOfConceptGitHub.domain;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Ref;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;


public class tree4 {

    private static final String PETCLINIC_URL = "https://github.com/wjcasperson/pet-clinic";
    private static final String SPRING5_URL = "https://github.com/wjcasperson/spring5-recipe-app";
    
    private static final String username = "MyUserName";
    private static final String password = "MyPassword";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GitAPIException {
        // set repo url
        String usedURL = PETCLINIC_URL;

        LsRemoteCommand cmd = Git.lsRemoteRepository();
        cmd.setHeads(true);
        cmd.setTags(true);
        cmd.setRemote(usedURL);
        cmd.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password));
        
        System.out.println("calling remote repository ========= " + usedURL);
        Collection<Ref> refs =cmd.call();
        
        System.out.println("All refs =========");
        for (Ref ref : refs) {
            System.out.println("Ref: " + ref);

        }

        final Map<String, Ref> map = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
                .setHeads(true)
                .setTags(true)
                .setRemote(usedURL)
                .callAsMap();

    }
}
```

Exception:
`Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/wjcasperson/pet-clinic: not authorized`
I have my correct username and password specified. I have an access token to use, but don't know how to use it when the credentialsProvider uses username/password.

Does anyone know how/where I have to change configuration/code so that this works? It works on public repos.

This is only my first hurdle. What I am trying to do is be able to display the contents of all files in the repo, so I have to walk/recurse the tree, and print out each file. It would seem like this is a pretty simple/common thing to do, but I don't find any good sample code.

I've checked all the doc I can find, so unless you have a link to a pretty clear and similar example, please don't post links to general user guides, etc.

The code works on a public repo. It works when I point it at my local copy of the repo.